# IE8: how do I turn off the warning about Javascript errors?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

When using IE8 I get this warning about 20 times a day:

```
"Errors on this webpage might cause it to work incorrectly"
(information about the javascript call that caused the break)
```

How do I make this go away? It gets old. I've unchecked the check box on that dialog many many times.

Comment: 1000 views, zero votes? Lame.

Comment: now it's even worse.  7000 views, no upvotes.  it's probably more a reflection of the hate for ie8 lol

Comment: @Sulla wow you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tools, Internet Options, Advanced, uncheck Display a Notification about every script error.

Note that it might be disabled by group policy.

Comment: You're right, disabled by group policy. That's why I didn't see it: greyed out. Nuts.